# Prevent jQuery change event from infinite recursion

Tags: jquery, onchange, preventdefault

I have a jQuery change event on a checkbox that makes an Ajax call, and then highlights the table row that the checkbox belongs to. I'm having a problem when the Ajax call reports an error - in this case I want to reverse the checkbox click (I'm using `that.prop("checked", !that.prop("checked"))` to do so). However, what is happening is that it enters an infinite loop of calling the change event. As you can see, in order to stop this behaviour I've tried to set a variable called ajaxInProgress, but it doesn't seem to be working as I'd hoped. Can anyone provide an alternative approach or spot the bug? I'm not sure that the way I'm resetting the checkbox is necessary - is it possible to reset the checkbox and still prevent the change event from kicking off?

```
var ajaxInProgress = false; //add this to stop recursive calls when errors occur 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".cc").change(function (e) {

    if (ajaxInProgress) return;

    var mode = "remove"
    if (jQuery(this).attr("checked")) {
       mode = "add"
    } 

    //grab the application ID from the checkbox ID
    var thisApp = this.id.substr(3);
    var that = jQuery(this);
    ajaxInProgress = true;
    jQuery.get("/particular/edit-ajax", { application_id: thisApp, 
                                          party_id: 1920, 
                                          party_rel_id: 21,
                                          mode: mode} , function(response) {
            if (response == 0) {
              that.closest('tr').removeClass('even').removeClass('odd').addClass('highlight');//highlight the tr
            } else {
              e.preventDefault();
              that.prop("checked", !that.prop("checked")); //reset the checkbox if there was an error
              alert("Please contact support - couldn't update database for application  "+thisApp+". Response was: "+response);
            }
    });       
    ajaxInProgress = false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because you have `ajaxInProgress = false;` after you `jQuery.get`.  This sets it to `false` before you even get anything back from your ajax request.  Move that line to inside the callback:

```
jQuery.get("/particular/edit-ajax",
    {
        application_id: thisApp,
        party_id: 1920,
        party_rel_id: 21,
        mode: mode
    },
    function(response) {
        ajaxInProgress = false;

        if (response == 0) {
            that.closest('tr').removeClass('even').removeClass('odd').addClass('highlight');//highlight the tr
        } else {
          e.preventDefault();
          that.prop("checked", !that.prop("checked")); //reset the checkbox if there was an error
          alert("Please contact support - couldn't update database for application  "+thisApp+". Response was: "+response);
        }
    }
);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/BgNfR/

My Fiddle is using `window.setTimeout` to simulate the ajax call.  I thought my solution wasn't working, but it was because I initially used `window.setInterval` so it *looked* like it was getting called over and over again, which it was, just wasn't simulating the ajax request as I should have been.

Comment: No, they are changing the checked state and want to stop the event from firing a second time.

Comment: Right, I'm getting at his flag wasn't ever staying `true` because of where he was resetting it.

Comment: Sorry, should've looked further, now that I have, I see my answer is wrong!

Answer (score 2):

It all seems very complicated, to much so, and I would just do :

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        function sendAjax(e) {
            var data = {
                application_id: this.id.substr(3), 
                party_id: 1920, 
                party_rel_id: 21,
                mode: this.checked?'add':'remove',
            },
                that=this;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: data
            }).done(function() {
                $(that).closest('tr').removeClass('even odd').addClass('highlight');
            }).fail(function(response) {
                e.preventDefault();
                that.checked = !that.checked;
                alert("Please contact support - couldn't update database for application  "+that.id.substr(3)+". Response was: "+response);
            }).always(function() {
                $(".cc").one('change', sendAjax);
            });
       }
       $(".cc").one('change', sendAjax);
    });
})(jQuery);
​
```

Comment: Very nice response. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

True using a "handling in progress" variable:

```
var ajaxInProgress = false, handlingInProgress = false; //add this to stop recursive calls when errors occur
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".cc").change(function (e) {
    if (handlingInProgress) return;
    if (ajaxInProgress) return;

    var mode = "remove"
    if (jQuery(this).attr("checked")) {
       mode = "add"
    } 

    //grab the application ID from the checkbox ID
    var thisApp = this.id.substr(3);
    var that = jQuery(this);
    ajaxInProgress = true;
    jQuery.get("/particular/edit-ajax", { application_id: thisApp, 
                                          party_id: 1920, 
                                          party_rel_id: 21,
                                          mode: mode} , function(response) {
            if (response == 0) {
              that.closest('tr').removeClass('even').removeClass('odd').addClass('highlight');//highlight the tr
            } else {
              e.preventDefault();
              that.prop("checked", !that.prop("checked")); //reset the checkbox if there was an error
              handlingInProgress = true; // Please see not below
              alert("Please contact support - couldn't update database for application  "+thisApp+". Response was: "+response);
            }
    });       
    ajaxInProgress = false;
    handlingInProgress = false; // 
  });
});
```

When you change the checkbox, the event fires again but because `handlingInProgress` is set to true it immediately breaks out of the handler.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that earlier where I have e.preventDefault(). Is that the right place to put it?

Comment: My answer is wrong, i'm rewriting it. This should stop other event handlers, but there's a chance it'll work. Do you have a demo?